# Why does returning *this result in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

```
class binaryOperators 
{
    public:
        int i;

        binaryOperators (int tempI = 0)
        {
            i = tempI;
        }

        binaryOperators operator+ (const binaryOperators &right);
};
```

---

```
binaryOperators binaryOperators :: operator+ (const binaryOperators &right)
{
    return binaryOperators (*this + right.i);
}

binaryOperators operator+ (const binaryOperators &left, const binaryOperators &right)
{
    return binaryOperators (left.i + right.i);
}

int main ()
{
    binaryOperators obj (10);

    obj = 11 + obj;

    obj = obj + 11;

    return 0;
}
```

So, here the statement `obj = 11 + obj;` calls the function with explicit argument specification.
and this one `obj = obj + 11;` calls the function which is the member of the class. Fine.

**The problem is that second call results in an infinite loop. 
What are the reasons and how to avoid that?**

Comment: Post the declaration of `binaryOperators`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion from `binaryOperators::i` (of type `int`) to `binaryOperators` is implicit (i.e. not declared `explicit`).

```
return binaryOperators (*this + right.i); // (1)
binaryOperators binaryOperators :: operator+ (const binaryOperators &right); // (2)
binaryOperators operator+ (const binaryOperators &left, const binaryOperators &right); // (3)
```

In the line (1) two `operator+` functions can be considered: The member version (2) and the free version (3). Since the LHS is of type `binaryOperators&`, the member version is applicable and preferred. Its argument is of type `const binaryOperators &`, and the argument given in line (1) is of type `int`, so the compiler tries to convert `int` to `const binaryOperators &`.

Since there is a non-`explicit` constructor with one argument, it is used as an implicit conversion from `int` to `const binaryOperators &`. Now we have two operands of types `binaryOperators&` and `const binaryOperators &`, the `operator+` in (2) can be called, and we are right where we started.

Lesson: Don't over-do implicit conversions.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Yes, just what I thought. Since `binaryOperators` has a conversion constructor from `int` (a one-argument constructor), implicit conversion happens. Write `explicit` in front of the constructor, and the problem will go away. Get into the habit for all one-argument constructors, saves you some worry.

Comment: @thiton Actually the problem won't quite go away, but at least the compiler will then tell you where the error was (i.e. no matching operator found).

Comment: thiton How does implicit conversion result in recursion? Please explain in little more detail.

Comment: Please `Now we have two operands of types binaryOperators& and const binaryOperators &, the operator+ in (2) can be called, and we are right where we started.` how does recursion start here?

Comment: Line (1) is from the `operator+` version (2). So when (2) is called, (1) is run, which calls (2), which runs (1) etc.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is in the statement:

```
return binaryOperators (*this + right.i);
```

`*this` is of type binaryOperators, so an operator is needed with a left-hand-side argument of type (or reference to) binaryOperators.

The possibly matching operators are the two you provide, so the right-hand-side argument needs to be of type `const binaryOperators &`. Thus the `right.i` is converted to a temporary binaryOperators using the appropriate constructor.

As a result, the member operator ends up calling itself, which calls itself, calling itself, etc., resulting in infinite recursion (what you see as an infinite loop).

You can probably fix this here by using:

```
return binaryOperators (this->i + right.i);
```

Comment: You said `*this is a binaryOperators, so an operator is needed with a left-hand-side argument of type (or reference to) binaryOperators.` Did you mean to say that because +/-/* can't work on objects ... okay I didn't understand that line..sorry.

Comment: @AnishaKaul I reworded it slightly, maybe it's more clear now. +-/* are all operators, and can work on class instances (aka objects) if and only if an appropriate operator overload is defined. Given `*this` as the left-hand-side, the only matching operators are those defined by you, of which the member is chosen. The right-hand-side is then converted accordingly (to a temporary binaryOperators). By using `this->i`, you switch to a different operator+ overload, namely one taking two ints, which is provided by the compiler.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. so, you mean that if I write (obj + 5) the compiler will search for a function with 2 parameters - a class object and an int?

Comment: @AnishaKaul Yes, precisely. If it doesn't find one that takes an int, it will try to convert the int (or the object) into something it can work with. In the given case the int is converted to best match the available parameter types.

Comment: Right, so the int is converted in the object of the class, so the situation is that left parameter is `this` and the right parameter is "int converted to object of the class"? so, at which point does the recursion start now?

Comment: @AnishaKaul At the point where the operator calls itself due to it being the best match. See thiton's revised answer, I think that makes it pretty clear.